# EditText with clicable links while not editable untill user change it by himself / Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin, hyperlink, android-edittext

Im trying to improve my ToDoList app.
I want to have my EditText at lauch as not-editable field so user can use links he saved for example in previous uses of application. If user would want to edit the field to save it do database he then can "activate" editing by pressing button or doubleclick or whatever.

Thats my first question here so I hope i'm not breaking any rules
Thanks in advice

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/taskDescEV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:background="@drawable/task_row_background"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="@string/taskDescTV_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|text"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/saveBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskNameEV" />


@InternalCoroutinesApi
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    taskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)
    val oldTaskName = args.itemName
    val oldTaskDesc = args.itemDesc
    taskNameEV.requestFocus()
    taskNameEV.setText(oldTaskName)
    taskDescEV.setText(oldTaskDesc)
    showKeyboard()

    taskDescEV.isEnabled = false



    saveBtn.setOnClickListener {

        if (taskNameEV.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            hideKeyboard()
            Handler().postDelayed(
                {
                    val taskNewName = taskNameEV.text.toString().capitalize(Locale.ROOT)
                    val taskNewDesc = taskDescEV.text.toString()
                    val oldTask = Task(oldTaskName, oldTaskDesc)
                    val newTask = Task(taskNewName, taskNewDesc)
                    taskViewModel.edit(oldTask, newTask)



                    navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_editFragment_to_listFragment)
                }, 300
            )


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "You can't add empty task", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is a `View`. It can be either enabled or disabled.

Assume your `EditText`'s name is `editText`:

`editText.setEnabled(false)` will disable the edit on it.

Edit:
Add these to your layout:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: But when i'm trying to do this i cant use link                             
        taskDescEV.isEnabled = true
        taskDescEV.isClickable = true
        taskDescEV.linksClickable = true
        taskDescEV.isCursorVisible = false
        taskDescEV.isFocusable = false

Comment: With textView there is no problem but i need edit functionality.